# RailwayJS & Cradle not working error

Tags: javascript, node.js, couchdb, cradle, railway.js

I am trying to use the cradle adapter for couchdb with railwayjs but it does not work.
This is a base install, and i have already installed cradle.

```
database.json
{ "development":
  { "driver":   "cradle"
  }
, "test":
  { "driver":   "memory"
  }
, "production":
  { "driver":   "memory"
  }
}


$ railway server 8888
Error while executing /cms/npmfile.js
Error while executing npmfile.js

/cms/node_modules/railway/lib/railway_utils.js:168
        throw e;
              ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'freezeSchema' of undefined
    at Schema.freeze (/cms/node_modules/jugglingdb/lib/schema.js:325:21)
    at module.exports.displayWarning (/cms/node_modules/jugglingdb/lib/railway.js:78:12)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at init (/cms/node_modules/jugglingdb/lib/railway.js:77:22)
    at Object.exports.init (/cms/node_modules/jugglingdb/index.js:14:29)
    at ctx.require (/cms/node_modules/railway/lib/extensions.js:38:17)
    at npmfile.js:2:1
    at Script.Object.keys.forEach.(anonymous function) [as runInNewContext] (vm.js:41:22)
    at Object.runCode (/cms/node_modules/railway/lib/railway_utils.js:165:11)
    at Object.exports.init (/cms/node_modules/railway/lib/extensions.js:21:15)
```

any ideas?